# how do you get a data attribute from a HTML string template literal?

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

This is the html code where i am rendering the content.

```
 <div class="game__container" id="empty_container">
          <a href="javascript:;" class="game__container_game-link"></a>
        </div>
```

inside JavaScript i have this async function, which returns each ID associated with each template string.

```
let cardContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('game__container_game-link');
    const showGame = async function(){ 
        try{
          // results coming out of Ajax call
            const markUp = results.map((game) =>{
    
        const text = ` 
        <div class="game__container" data-id="${id}">
              <a href="javascript:;" class="game__container_game-link" ></a>    
       </div>
        `;
    return text;
    
    }).join('')
    
    gameContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',markUp);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < cardContainer.length; i++) {
      cardContainer[i].addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
        console.log('ok!',e.target.getAttribute('data-id'));
      })}
    
        } catch(err){
    console.log(err);
        }};
```

this return 'ok' on each element but the data-id returns null.

i tried this as well.did not work at all.

```
    const range = document.createRange();
    let frag = range.createContextualFragment(text);
    gameContainer.appendChild(frag);
     const selectNode = document.querySelectorAll('.game__container_game-link');
     
for(var i = 0;i < selectNode.length;i++){
   selectNode[i].addEventListener('click',(e)=>{ console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-id')}
)
```

how would you get this data attribute inside of a html string and attach event handler on this html string?

Comment: Please add the code where you define `cardContainer`.

Comment: Side note: I see no reason for showGame to be async when everything inside it is synchronous

Comment: @jmargolisvt added :) sorry about that.

Comment: @charlietfl plz note i make a AJAX call here. Thank you! :)

Comment: Your data attribute is not defined on the `cardContainer[i]` element itself, but on its parent `<div>`. So use `e.target.parentNode.dataset.id`.

Comment: @Bergi OMG! Thank you so SO MUCH!! You just unstuck me from a month old spaghetti!
Wish you a great and blissful year! Thank you again!